# How can i see cookie folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, cookies

When i serialize a value and stored in a cookie, i can see cookie text file in Cookies folder. But if i dont serialize that value, i can't see cookie text file.

There is my code:

(Serialize)

```
  BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  bf.Serialize(ms, "111");
  byte[] bArr = ms.ToArray();
  string sCookieVal = Convert.ToBase64String(bArr);
  HttpCookie cook = new HttpCookie("cookieName");
  cook.Value = sCookieVal;
  cook.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cook);
```

(unserialize)

```
  HttpCookie cook = new HttpCookie("cookieName");
  cook.Value = "111";
  cook.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cook);
```

Why i can't see unserialize value in cookies folder? Where is it stored ? A phsycal path or virtual path?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, I'm not sure what you are really trying to do here. Cookies are not stored server-side, right?

It looks like you're trying to add a cookie to the response. That means that the cookie is going to be sent from the server to the client's browser that is viewing whatever ASPX this code is in.

Depending on their browser, that cookie could be stored any number of ways. I don't think serializing has anything to do with it. I'm not sure that your "serializing" code does anything. Maybe you should read more about cookies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie